# implement uniqueness , constraints while inserting data in a column with another column

Tags: c#, .net, sql, sql-server, sql-server-2005

I have a table A with columns Aname , Work

```
create table A(Aname varchar(40) , Work varchar(40) )
```

The table already has the below data inserted:

```
INSERT INTO A VALUES ('GREAME ','PLAYER')
```

### Aname                   ||         Work

### GREAME           PLAYER

now i want that when i insert a new record, Aname--GREAME , Work---SALESMAN, then it is

inserted , but if i insert this : Aname--GREAME Work--PLAYER again, then it is not inserted

I want this:

### **Aname   ||    Work**

### GREAME  PLAYER

### GREAME  PLAYER --- COULD NOT BE INSERTED

### GREAME  SALESMAN   --- COULD BE INSERTED

That is  , the Work column checks for uniqueness when the to be inserted value of Aname

already exists.

How do i implement this? Please help with code.

EDIT------

in the insert query, the Aname column would be picked up from another table B
then how do i do it?

Comment: ALTER TABLE A ADD CONSTRAINT PK_A PRIMARY KEY (Aname,Work)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A unique constraint or a primary key will prevent you from insert with an error/exception. This insert will just not insert the row it it already exists.

```
insert into A (Aname, Work)
select 'GREAME', 'PLAYER'
where not exists (select *
                  from A
                  where Aname = 'GREAME' and Work = 'PLAYER')
```

Comment: thanks a lot sir, your answer really helped me, but i could accept only one , if that wasn't a rule, i would have accepted all posted here –

Comment: @sqlchild Please add a new question to SO where you include this insert statement and your data model for both tables and a description of what you want to do. It would also be great if you supplied sample data for the tables and what the expected result should be after the insert.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5216292/insert-record-in-one-table-by-copying-single-row-of-a-single-column-from-another    ------- sir ,i have posted the new question here

Answer (score 1):

And if you need the combination of AName and Work to be Unique then

```
ALTER TABLE A ADD CONSTRAINT U_NameWork UNIQUE(AName, Work)
```

But if you need AName to be Unique irrespective of Work then

```
ALTER TABLE A ADD CONSTRAINT U_Name UNIQUE(AName)
```

Edit: As per SanjeevKumar, making (AName, Work) a composite PRIMARY KEY will also work provided you have no other PK, although you might also consider a surrogate PK.