# insert record in one table by copying single row of a single column from another table

Tags: c#, .net, sql, sql-server, sql-server-2005

I have a table `SEND` with one column `Aname`:

```
Aname   
------
GREAME  
PETER
```

Another table `RECEIVE` with 2 columns:

```
Aname                              Permission
-----------------------------------------------
GREAME (copied from table SEND)    'my own value will be inserted here,
                                    specified in insert query'

PETER  (copied from table  SEND)    'my own value will be inserted here,
                                    specified in insert query'
```

Now as shown above, I want to insert into a new table `RECEIVE` only the `Aname` column  from table `SEND` and in the second column I would insert a new value.

Also, I want that no duplicate values could be inserted in `RECEIVE` table:

I want this:

```
Aname   Permission
---------------------
GREAME  PLAYER
GREAME  PLAYER --- COULD NOT BE INSERTED
GREAME  SALESMAN   --- COULD BE INSERTED
```

I am using this query :

```
insert into receive(Aname, Permission)
  select Aname , 'Select' 
  from SEND
  where not exists
     (select * from RECEIVE where Aname = 'GREAME' and Permission = 'select')
```

This query takes both the names GREAME & PETER from the `SEND` table and  inserts them into the `RECEIVE` table, but I want that only GREAME is picked up, not PETER.

How do I do it?

IT TAKES ALL THE ROWS FROM TABLE SEND, and inserts them in table RECEIVE, but I want that only one row gets inserted. So I want the query to be like this but it gives syntax error:

```
insert into RECEIVE(Aname , Permission)
  select Aname , 'select' 
  from SEND
  WHERE Aname = 'GREAME'  -------------this line gives error
  where not exists
    (select *  from RECEIVE where aname = 'GREAME' and Permission = 'select')
```

Comment: @msrc_s : sir ,  its giving syntax error, and i know that we can't use two where clauses, but its the description of the work which i want the query to perform.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can't have **two WHERE clauses** in one statement:

```
insert into RECEIVE(Aname , Permission)
  select Aname , 'select' 
  from SEND
  WHERE Aname = 'GREAME'   <=== WHERE #1
  where not exists         <=== WHERE #2
    (select *  from RECEIVE where aname = 'GREAME' and Permission = 'select')
```

You need to change the second part to an AND:

```
insert into RECEIVE(Aname , Permission)
  select Aname , 'select' 
  from SEND
  WHERE Aname = 'GREAME'  
  AND not exists
    (select *  from RECEIVE where aname = 'GREAME' and Permission = 'select')
```